# Box around tikz-cd diagram, without ampersand replacement

Tags: tikz-cd, ampersand

**Problem statement:**

I'd like to put a box around a tikz-cd diagram, without needing to use ampersand replacement. Using \fbox seems to require ampersand replacement.

**Demonstration:**

The following gives an error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\fbox{
  \begin{tikzcd}       %error: must use ampersand replacement
    A \ar[r, "f"] & B
  \end{tikzcd}
}
\]

\end{document}
```

The following works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\fbox{
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
    A \ar[r, "f"] \& B
  \end{tikzcd}
}
\]

\end{document}
```

**Complaint:**

It is annoying to have to use ampersand replacement every time I want a box!

**Question:** Is there another way to draw a box around a tikz-cd diagram that does not cause the ampersand problem? More generally, is there a way to embed a tikzcd diagram as a node in a tikz picture?

*Thanks!*

Comment: Don't put a CD as a node into another TikZ diagram. For just boxing you can use the [`fbox` style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665758). The [`backgrounds` library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664104) provides more customization. If you want to use a CD as part of a bigger TikZ picture, you can use [a small adjustment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665688) to the `tikzcd` environment so that it can be used inside a tikzpicture almost as easy as the `\matrix` it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mybox/.style={draw, inner sep=5pt}]
\node[mybox] (box){%
  \begin{tikzcd}
    A \ar[r, "f"] & B
  \end{tikzcd}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can adjust the `inner sep` in `mybox` and/or add options such as `thick`, `rounded corners`, `fill=`, `draw=` etc. for different style boxes. For example,

```
[mybox/.style={draw=blue, fill=yellow!50, very thick, rounded corners,
    inner sep=5pt}]
```

will produce

[image]

Comment: Thank you @CarLaTeX for indicating best practice here. I edited my response.

Answer (score 7):

The `tikz-cd` environment actually is a `tikzpicture` with a `matrix` inside, which it's itself a node, you could append a style and tell `tikz` to draw its border.

Moreover, for the same reason (`tikz-cd` environment is a `tikzpicture`), be careful to inserting it in another `tikzpicture` (nesting `tikzpicture`s is not recommended). You could use `execute at end picture` or `remember picture` and `overlay` instead.

If you want to use the same formatting for more than one commutative diagram of yours, you could create a style, possibly with some parameters.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\tikzcdset{
    boxedcd/.style={
        every matrix/.append style={
            draw=red,
            thick,
            fill=yellow!50!white,
            rounded corners,
            #1
        },
    },
}

\begin{document} 
    \[ 
    \begin{tikzcd}[every matrix/.append style={draw, inner ysep=4pt}]
        A \ar[r, "f"] & B 
    \end{tikzcd} 
    \] 
    Of course, you can set the node as you like:
    \[ 
    \begin{tikzcd}[every matrix/.append style={draw=red, 
        fill=yellow, inner ysep=4pt, rounded corners}]
        A \ar[r, "f"] & B 
    \end{tikzcd} 
    \]
    Example of \texttt{execute at end picture}:
    \[ 
    \begin{tikzcd}[every matrix/.append style={name=mymatr},
        execute at end picture={
            \draw[red,rounded corners] (mymatr.south west) -- (mymatr.south east) -- ([yshift=4pt]mymatr.north east) -- ([yshift=4pt]mymatr.north west) -- cycle;
        }]
        A \ar[r, "f"] & B 
    \end{tikzcd} 
    \]
    Example of use of \texttt{overlay}:
    \[ 
    \begin{tikzcd}[remember picture,
        every matrix/.append style={name=mymatrix}]
        A \ar[r, "f"] & B 
    \end{tikzcd} 
    \]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[blue,rounded corners] (mymatrix.south west) -- (mymatrix.south east) -- ([yshift=4pt]mymatrix.north east) -- ([yshift=4pt]mymatrix.north west) -- cycle; 
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \noindent Example of use of a \texttt{stlye}:
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}[boxedcd={inner sep=1pt}]
        A \arrow[r] & B
    \end{tikzcd}\quad
    \begin{tikzcd}[boxedcd={inner ysep=4pt}]
        A \arrow[r, "f"] & B
    \end{tikzcd}\quad
    \begin{tikzcd}[boxedcd={inner xsep=4pt, inner ysep=2pt}]
        A \arrow[r] & B\\
        C \arrow[u, "g"]
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Sandy G scooped me. Here is my proposal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{tabular}{|c|}
  \hline
  \begin{tikzcd}    
   A \ar[r, "f"] & B
  \end{tikzcd}\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're satisfied with the standard `\fbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newenvironment{boxedtikzcd}
 {\begin{lrbox}{\boxedtikzcdbox}\begin{tikzcd}}
 {\end{tikzcd}\end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\boxedtikzcdbox}}}
\newsavebox{\boxedtikzcdbox}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{boxedtikzcd}
A \arrow[r, "f"] & B
\end{boxedtikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]