# how to resolve incompatibility of tikz-cd and external

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, tikz-external

I am trying to export tikz pictures using tikz-cd to pdf. In order to run the tikz-cd, I had to disable the external library as shown below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{etoolbox,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

 \AtBeginEnvironment{tikzcd}{\tikzexternaldisable}
 \AtEndEnvironment{tikzcd}{\tikzexternalenable}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
 ABC \arrow[loop right, "x"]{} \arrow[loop left, "y"]{} \arrow[out=240, 
in=320, 
 loop] \arrow[out=220, in=300, loop,crossing over, "z" swap, pos=0.58] \\
\end{tikzcd}


\begin{tikzcd}
D \arrow[loop left]{} \arrow[d]{} \arrow[r]{} & AC \arrow[out=240, in=320, 
loop] 
\arrow[out=220, in=300, loop,crossing over]  \\
DB \arrow[out=240, in=320, loop] \arrow[out=220, in=300, loop,crossing over]  
& 
\\
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

and as mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172432/32412). I tried to use the other [answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173181/32412) mentioned but they didn't work for me. 
How do I export each tikzcd picture to pdf separately?

Comment: Just wondering here: what would be the benefit of externalizing tikz-CD diagrams?

Comment: The `externalize` library documentation is clear: you can only externalize `tikzpicture` environments. Since `tikzcd` internally calls `\tikzpicture`, the library gets confused and can't find the end of its job anyway.

Comment: tikzcd is not too far away from a tikzpicture. Eventually it sets up a `\matrix` node with appropriate options.

Comment: @daleif Some journals require to submit figure pdfs separately. And if you have many tikz-cd figures in your file, externalizing helps to export them to pdfs in one go. As of now, I am using standalone document class to make a pdf for each tikz-cd figure

Comment: @egreg I guess another version of my question would be how to export multiple tikz-cd figures to separate pdfs in one run

Answer (score 2):

The following solution only works when the proper LaTeX enviroments (i.e. `\begin{tikzcd}` and `\end{tikzcd}`)  are used. Using `\tikzcd … \endtikzcd` will break externalizing or just not compile.
A solution that's a bit more sophisticated will be needed to cover all use-cases.
(Though, since `external` only works with LaTeX in the first place there aren't many left, I believe.)

---

The `external` library needs `\end{tikzpicture}` to be on the input stream when `\begin{tikzpicture}` triggers the library's mechanisms.

I'd suggest adjusting the `tikzcd` environment so that it can be used inside a TikZ picture which doesn't interfere with the externalization process. This means you need

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzcd}
…
\end{tikzcd}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

to externalize a CD. (This is also how it works with PGFPlots.)

In the code below I'm adding the necessary check to the `\tikzcd` macro (i.e. `\begin{tikzcd}`) which detects whether you're using the `tikzcd` environment inside of a `tikzpicture` by checking whether `\path` is TikZ' own `\path`.

If it is it will change the `tikzpicture` that is used inside `tikzcd` into a `scope` which will accepts the optional argument of `tikzcd` instead.

If you have used the `tikzcd` diagram outside of a `tikzpicture` (i.e. `\path` is not TikZ's `\path`) then it will disable the externalization for this diagram.

This will also break putting a nesting TikZ pictures but this is never a good idea to begin with.

However it allows to use multiple CDs in one TikZ picture. (Remember, these are just `\matrix`es. However you need to use

```
\begin{tikzcd}[every matrix/.append style={…}]
```

to change the option to the `\matrix` (e.g. the `name` or any placements). It'd probably help to define a shortcut like

```
\tikzcdset{matrices/.style={every matrix/.append style={#1}}}
```

to make it more easier to change the style.

---

The `\pgfkeys` stuff is basically `etoolbox`'s `\preto` but with on-board ressources of TikZ.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd,external}
\tikzexternalize
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
  /utils/temp/.initial/.expand once=\tikzcd,
  /utils/temp/.prefix=%
    \ifx\path\tikz@command@path % we're inside a tikzpicture
      \let\tikzpicture\scope
      \let\endtikzpicture\endscope
    \else % we're not inside a tikzpicture, disable externalizing
      \tikzexternaldisable
    \fi,
  /utils/temp/.get=\tikzcd}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzcd}
 ABC \arrow[loop right, "x"]
     \arrow[loop left,  "y"]
     \arrow[out=240, in=320, loop]
     \arrow[out=220, in=300, loop, crossing over, "z" swap, pos=0.58] \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzcd}
  D  \arrow[loop left]
     \arrow[d]
     \arrow[r]
& AC \arrow[out=240, in=320, loop]
     \arrow[out=220, in=300, loop, crossing over]  \\
  DB \arrow[out=240, in=320, loop]
     \arrow[out=220, in=300, loop, crossing over]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzcd}
 ABC \arrow[loop right, "x"]
     \arrow[loop left,  "y"]
     \arrow[out=240, in=320, loop]
     \arrow[out=220, in=300, loop, crossing over, "z" swap, pos=0.58] \\
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
  D  \arrow[loop left]
     \arrow[d]
     \arrow[r]
& AC \arrow[out=240, in=320, loop]
     \arrow[out=220, in=300, loop, crossing over]  \\
  DB \arrow[out=240, in=320, loop]
     \arrow[out=220, in=300, loop, crossing over]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

Three PDFs:

1. First `tikzpicture` externalized.
2. Second `tikzpicture` externalized.
3. Main document with four TikZ pictures.

Answer (score 2):

Just to say that `memoize` can now externalise `tikzcd`, at least if you understand things better than I do and figure out the correct options. These are courtesy of [`memoize`'s author, Sašo Živanović](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64689784#64689784).

```
\documentclass{article}
% addaswyd o gwestiwn user25957: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/493622/
\usepackage{memoize}
\mmzset{%
  %   path={dir=memos}, % v. 1
  %   mkdir, % v. 1
  prefix=memos/, % v. 1.1 and later
  % Sašo Živanović: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64689784#64689784
  auto={tikzcd}{memoize,verbatim},
}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  ABC \arrow[loop right, "x"]{} \arrow[loop left, "y"]{} \arrow[out=240, 
  in=320, 
  loop] \arrow[out=220, in=300, loop,crossing over, "z" swap, pos=0.58] \\
\end{tikzcd}


\begin{tikzcd}
  D \arrow[loop left]{} \arrow[d]{} \arrow[r]{} & AC \arrow[out=240, in=320, 
  loop] 
  \arrow[out=220, in=300, loop,crossing over]  \\
  DB \arrow[out=240, in=320, loop] \arrow[out=220, in=300, loop,crossing over]  
  & 
  \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image: memoized tikzcd diagrams]

Comment: `path` doesn't seem to be recognized anymore (using v1.2.0). Instead, use `memo dir=<name>`, which saves the files in `<name>.memo.dir`

Comment: @red_trumpet Thanks. Actually, it should be `prefix` now. I'll update my answer. (I don't like dots in directory names except as the first character.) And `mkdir` is unnecessary.