# Nested and boxed sub-diagrams using tikz-cd package

Tags: tikz-cd

Is there a simple way of making nested and boxed sub-diagrams using the tikz-cd package?

For example (from Lawvere and Schanuel, *Conceptual Mathematics*):

[image: Commutative diagram]

I currently use the following environment to create boxed commutative diagrams, which works nicely:

```
\newenvironment{tikzcdb}
                     {\begin{lrbox}{\tikzcdbox}\begin{tikzcd}}
                     {\end{tikzcd}\end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\tikzcdbox}}}
\newsavebox{\tikzcdbox}
```

I can't figure out how to do the nesting though, and then do nesting AND boxing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What mean "simple" to you? What you try so far? Where you stuck in your effort? You should be aware that this site is not service "we-do-your-task-instead-of you" ...

Comment: I'd use the key `boxed` as defined in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664104) (we can further fine tune the padding and whatnot so that it is the same as with `\fbox`. We can also [use multiple TikZ-CDiagrams in one TikZ picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665688). Your picture could also be produced by just one CD where we add those boxes with other TikZ means.

Comment: Have you thought about how the box should look like if an arrow goes beyond the matrix' borders?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is helpful, it will depend on the kind of diagrams you need to do.

1. We patch the `tikzcd` environment so that it detects when it is used inside a `tikzpicture` …
2. and add a few forwarded keys up so that the `tikzcd` environment acts as much as a normal TikZ `\matrix` as it can.
3. The combination of `between origins`, `overlay`ed TikZ labels and a custom `padding` for each TikZ-CD matrix make sure the boxes (i.e. the drawn matrices) have the same size. Of course, for this, all dots need to be the same size.
4. The `cd arrow` key emulates as easy as possible TikZ-CD's own `\ar(row)` command.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{cd, positioning, quotes}
\makeatletter
\tikzcdset{
  /utils/temp/.initial/.expand once=\tikzcd,
  /utils/temp/.prefix=\ifx\path\tikz@command@path\let\tikzpicture\scope\let\endtikzpicture\endscope\fi,
  /utils/temp/.get=\tikzcd,
  enable tikzcd quotes/.code=%
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/handlers/first char syntax/\expandafter\meaning\string"}{\tikz@quote@parser}%
    \def\tikz@quotes@as##1##2{matrices={label={[direction shorthands,##2]##1}}},
  forwarded keys/.style={% the \pgfkeyslet stuff makes sure the keys work normal in an arrow label
    #1/.style={matrices={/tikz/#1={##1}}},
    every label/.append code=\pgfkeyslet{/tikz/commutative diagrams/#1/.@cmd}\pgfutil@undefined}}
\makeatother
\tikzcdset{
  forwarded keys/.list={below, left, right, above, name, anchor, matrix anchor},
  matrices/.style={every matrix/.append style={#1}},
  padding/.style args={#1:#2}{
    matrices={inner xsep={(#1)*1ex}, inner ysep={(#2)*1ex}}},
  tight/.style={inner sep=+.25ex}}
\tikzset{
  Dot Diagram/.code=%
    \tikzcdset{
      tikzcd to/.tip={Stealth[scale width=.75, inset=+.75pt +.5]}, % arrow tip
      matrices={draw, outer sep=+.5ex},
      diagrams={% between origins + overlay labels + padding makes it
                % easy to create matrices that have same dimensions
        enable tikzcd quotes,
        row sep={3em,between origins}, column sep={5em,between origins},
        /tikz/every label/.style={% the labels on matrices
          path only, math nodes, shape=asymmetrical rectangle,
          inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt},
        cells={
          /tikz/label distance=+-1ex, % because of outer sep=.5ex
          /tikz/every label/.style={% we need to reset all dot settings
            shape=rectangle, path only, overlay,
            commutative diagrams/every label},
          nodes={% these are our dots
            shape=circle, fill, inner sep=+0pt,
            outer sep=+.5ex, minimum size=+.7ex}}}},
  math nodes/.style={execute at begin node=$, execute at end node=$},
  cd arrow/.style={% a very simple TikZ-CD's \arrow implementation
    every edge/.append style={
      nodes={math nodes, commutative diagrams/every label},
      commutative diagrams/every arrow}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[Dot Diagram, node distance=1.5em]
\begin{tikzcd}[name=aa,              "{{}=A^2}" right, padding=3:3.1]
  |["{(s, t)}"]|                                 & |["{(t, t)}"]| \\
  |["{(s, s)}" below]| \ar[ur, "{(a, a)}" tight] & |["{(t, s)}" below]|
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[name=da, below=of aa, "{{}=A}" right, padding=3:1.7]
  |["s" left]| \ar[r, "a"] & |["t" right]|
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[name=la, left =of aa, "{A={}}" left,  padding=1.7:3.1]
|["t"]| \\ |["s" below]| \ar[u, "a"]
\end{tikzcd}
% a very simple TikZ-CD's \arrow implementation
\path[cd arrow] (aa) edge["p_1"] (da)
                     edge["p_2"] (la);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I don't actually need the dots in the diagrams, I just want to use standard tikz-cd commutative diagrams with boxes around them and using, e.g. (s,s) for the nodes. I tried to edit your code to remove the dots, but failed.