# How to draw a framed box adjusted to its content?

Tags: tcolorbox, box

I know that the package `tcolorbox` provides the option `\tcbox`. But apparently it isn't able to handle linebreaks, quotations ( e.g csquotes display equation) or mathmode content. I think that `\begin{tcolorbox}` is amazing and it does exactly what I want, except for adjusting its width to the content.

All I want is a command that creates an adjusted frame around an arbitrary piece of text and allows me to use linebreaks and environments like equations,quotations etc.. I don't care about pagebreaks.

Can I still achieve that with the `tcolorbox` package or are there other options?
I'm a beginner with LaTeX, thanks in advance

EDIT: to be more precise, using the `\boxed` command gives me the general output I want to achieve:

```
\begin{equation*}
  \boxed{
   \begin{aligned}
   &p = \text{Intervallverhältnis von 1 Cent} \\
   &2 = \text{Intervallverhältnis der reinen Oktave} \\ \\
   &p^{1200} = 2 \longrightarrow p = \sqrt[1200]{2}
   \end{aligned}
  }
\end{equation*}
```

[image: image of output]

This is exactly what I want to achieve using `tcolorbox` and its frames. A frame around a (centered) piece of math, with automatically adjusted width.

I already tried using the `\tcbox` command:

```
\tcbox{
 \begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
  &p = \text{Intervallverhältnis von 1 Cent} \\
  &2 = \text{Intervallverhältnis der reinen Oktave} \\ \\
  &p^{1200} = 2 \longrightarrow p = \sqrt[1200]{2}
  \end{aligned}
 \end{equation*}
}
```

This results in package `amsmath` error messages and while the frame is adjusted to its content like I want it, the whole box isn't centered anymore but aligned to the left.

Comment: Could you please show what you tried so far using the `tcolorbox` package? Please also clarify "except for adjusting its width to the content". How should the output look like? Probably a sketch could help clarify.

Comment: If linebreaks have to be automatic, then the width needs to be fixed. You can't have both auto-width and auto-linebreaks at the same time (there is `varwidth`, but the width adjustment is then defined by forced line breaks, or the maximum line length—like a whole paragraph on a single line). So, you need to *precisely* describe what you want to do.

Comment: Have you looked at the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408497/125871)?

Comment: @leandriis I edited the post, adding an example for the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\tcbhighmath` might be interesting for that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{equation*}
\tcbhighmath{
  \begin{aligned}
  &p = \text{Intervallverhältnis von 1 Cent} \\
  &2 = \text{Intervallverhältnis der reinen Oktave} \\ \\
  &p^{1200} = 2 \longrightarrow p = \sqrt[1200]{2}
  \end{aligned}
  }
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

The style of the box can also be customized. `\tcbset{highlight math style={colframe=black,colback=white,boxrule=1pt, sharp corners}}` for example give the following output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question: is the `\tcbset` command supposed to be in the preamble? If not can I add any number of `\tcbset` in my code to change the appearance of each box?

Comment: You can use the `tcbset` command in the preamble to change the style of all boxes in the document. Alternatively you can place the `\tcbst` command somewhere in the document and the style will be applied to all following boxes.